# A function that ask for a number and squares all the numbers to that number and sums them

Tags: javascript, function, math, for-loop

I need to create a javascript function will calculate the total of the square of all numbers from 1 to the number entered and return that value summed. Here is my code so far.

```
function sumOfSquares(num) {
    var i;

    for (i=0,i<=num,i++){
        var sum=0;
        var i = i*i;
        sum = i;
}
     document.write("The sum of squares for numbers up to and including " +num+ "is " +sum+ ) ;
}
var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
sumOfSquares(num);
```

Comment: So is there a problem? If you are just looking for people to review your code, you should post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: You defined `i` twice, once at the beginning of the function and once inside the loop. Only define a variable once. Variables created with the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) statement in JavaScript [have function scope](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), not block scope. Block scope will eventually come to JS with the ES6 `let` statement but none of the browsers properly support it yet. Also, `document.write` is outdated (and IMO evil). Use `console.log` for debugging instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the code.

```
function sumOfSquares(num) {
    var i;

    for (i=0,i<=num,i++){ // You need to use ; to separate the
                          // initialization, condition and
                          // final-expression in the for statement, not a
                          // comma. When using comma to separate them, all 3
                          // expressions run as the initializer; this
                          // loop doesn't have a condition or a
                          // final-expression, so it will loop forever (or
                          // until the browser throws up a long-running
                          // script warning).
                          //
                          // Also, since you want to count up from 1, you
                          // should start i at 1 instead of 0. In this case
                          // starting at zero is harmless since 0 + 0 * 0 is
                          // still zero, but it adds a needless round and in
                          // other situations this kind of error could cause
                          // bigger problems.

        var sum=0; // You are setting sum to zero at the top of every loop,
                   // only the last squaring will be added to the 0 and
                   // become the final sum.
        var i = i*i; // You are changing the value of i, this will cause
                     // things to get skipped. Between this line and the i++
                     // instead of increasing linearly 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc,
                     // the value of i over the first few loops would
                     // look something like:
                     // 
                     // 0 * 0     = 0
                     // 0++       = 1
                     // 1 * 1     = 1
                     // 1++       = 2
                     // 2 * 2     = 4
                     // 4++       = 5
                     // 5 * 5     = 25
                     // 25++      = 26
                     // 26 * 26   = 676
                     // 676++     = 677
                     // 677 * 676 = 456976
                     // 
                     // That is i increasing exponentially! Not sum!

        sum = i;
    }
     document.write("The sum of squares for numbers up to and including " +num+
       "is " +sum+ ) ; // There is an extra + at the end of the expression
                       // inside of the write method, this will cause a
                       // parsing error when the browser tries to load the
                       // script.

    // You don't return anything so anyone who runs this function would get
    // undefined back. That is if the above code hadn't gotten stuck in an
    // infinite loop.
}
var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:")); // It is not as critical as it used
                                               // to be, but a radix should
                                               // always be used with
                                               // parseInt.
sumOfSquares(num);
```

A proper version of it might look like this.

```
var sumOfSquares = function (num) {
  var i,
    sum = 0;

  for (i = 1; i <= num; i += 1) {
    sum += i * i;
  }
  return sum;
}

var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"), 10); // Specify the radix as
                                                   // 10 to make sure the
                                                   // number is interpreted
                                                   // as a decimal.

console.log("The sum of squares for numbers up to and including " + num + " is " +
  sumOfSquares(num)) ;
```

The first thing you might notice is that I used a
[function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)
instead of a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function),
there are a few [reasons I've gotten in to this habit](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/).

The reasons for some of the other stylistic choices I've made (declaring all the
vars at the top of the function, using `i += 1` instead of `i++`, etc) are well
explained in Douglas Crockford's excellent talk [Programming Style and Your
Brain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY) and/or his great book
*JavaScript: The Good Parts*.

For the foreseeable future, a [radix must always be used with `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix).
ES5 removes this requirement and defaults `parseInt` to decimal when no radix
is specified but [not all browsers support this
yet!](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#parseInt%28%29_ignores_leading_zeros)
Most prominently if you need to support IE8 or earlier they don't support it.
This is becoming less of a problem at this point since at this point IE8 is
pretty ancient but it is something to be aware of.

Learn to use your browser's console, most browsers have one including
[Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console),
[Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), 
[IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)9+ and
[Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/).
`document.write` is outdated and [has lots of
problems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y2Y0U-2qJMs#t=1082s),
for debugging instead `console.log` should be used.
[`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)
will log things to the console for you, not just strings, you can log arrays,
objects just about everything.

- [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [comma , operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `sum` variable outside of that for loop. Keeping it in there is setting it back to 0 every time. Also don't declare a variable `i` again for the 'square' value, since your'e already using `i` for the loop. You can actually omit the new variable

```
var sum=0;
for (i=0,i<=num,i++){
    sum += i*i;
}
     document.write("The sum of squares for numbers up to and including " +num+ "is " + sum ) ;
}
var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
sumOfSquares(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as **Abdul** said, but **i** started with **1**, because multiply of `0 * 0 = 0`

```
var sum=0;
for (i=1,i<=num,i++){
    var square = i*i;
    sum += square;
}
```